# What does the Coq command Require Import Ltac do?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, coq-extraction

When I am looking at the QuickChick project, I encountered the sentence `Require Import Ltac.` I don't know what this does and where the `Ltac` module is. I found a file `plugins/ltac/Ltac.v`, but this couldn't be the one since this file is empty (by the way, what is the purpose of including an empty file anyway?). I tried `Locate Ltac.` but I got `Error: Syntax error: [constr:global] expected after 'Ltac' (in [locatable]).`, which is more confusing.

What does the `Ltac` module do, where is the `Ltac.v` file, and why doesn't the `Loacte` command work in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Require Import Ltac.` is indeed `Coq.ltac.Ltac`, the empty file you found! I am not sure why there's an empty file there, but it was introduced when [Ltac was moved to a plugin](https://github.com/coq/coq/commit/653de32139ecee3114779a5ee2961c58793889e5). Perhaps it serves as a placeholder for if some of the Ltac implementation were moved into Coq rather than being an OCaml plugin. In any case I think there's little reason for QuickChick to import it, unless they're anticipating some change to Coq I don't know about.

Because of a conflict with the vernacular command `Locate Ltac` (which is giving you a syntax error), you need to instead use `Locate Module` explicitly. The same goes for `Print Module`.

`Locate Module Ltac` reports `Module Coq.ltac.Ltac`, which tells you that you're indeed looking at `theories/ltac/Ltac.v`, and `Print Module Ltac` shows an empty module. However, that second bit is misleading, since what look like empty modules can still have notations (that's not the case here, but just FYI).

Comment: Thanks! However, I still don't know why `Locate Ltac.` fails. `Locate` works fine for almost any imported Modules. For example, if in `coqtop` you try `Require Import Morphisms.` and then `Locate Morphisms.`, it tells you `Module Coq.Classes.Morphisms` (you get the same thing if you try `Locate Module Morphisms.`). Why must I use `Locate Module` in the `Ltac` case?

Comment: The reason to add this file was due to the way the build system works, IIRC.

Comment: @JimYu This is because `Locate Ltac` also exists,  and there is a confusion between your module named `Ltac` and the `Locate Ltac` command (e.g. `Locate Ltac idtac.`).

Comment: Ah, thanks @eponier! I'll update my answer since yours is really the correct explanation.